# How to use mocks with MicronautLambdaHandler in a JUnit class annotated @MicronautTest?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-aws

I'd like to mock out collaborators as documented [here](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#_mocking_collaborators) with my `MicronautLambdaHandler` application, though if you just instantiate `MicronautLambdaHandler` by calling its constructor, it apparently won't pick up anything from your test context.

Specifically, this doesn't work as expected:

```kotlin
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.testutils.AwsProxyRequestBuilder
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.internal.testutils.MockLambdaContext
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContextBuilder
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import io.micronaut.context.env.Environment
import io.micronaut.http.HttpHeaders
import io.micronaut.http.HttpMethod
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import io.micronaut.function.aws.proxy.MicronautLambdaHandler
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.AuthenticationException
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.AuthenticationFailed
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
import io.micronaut.security.authentication.AuthenticationResponse
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MockBean
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.reactivex.Maybe
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher
import java.lang.RuntimeException
import javax.inject.Inject

@MicronautTest
class ManualInstantiationTest {
    @Inject
    lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    @Inject
    lateinit var authenticationProvider: AuthenticationProvider

    @MockBean(AuthenticationProvider::class)
    fun authenticationProviderMock() = mockk<AuthenticationProvider>()

    @Test
    fun testLoginHandler() {
        every { authenticationProvider.authenticate(any(), any()) } answers {
            Maybe.error<AuthenticationResponse>(
                AuthenticationException(
                    AuthenticationFailed("Incorrect password")
                )
            ).toFlowable()
        }

        val handler = MicronautLambdaHandler()
        val loginRequest = Registration("username", "password")
        val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginRequest)
        val request = AwsProxyRequestBuilder("/login", HttpMethod.POST.toString())
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(json)
            .build()
        val lambdaContext: Context = MockLambdaContext()
        // this.authenticationProvider is never used
        val response = handler.handleRequest(request, lambdaContext)
    }
}
```

I've also tried `@Inject`ing a field of type `MicronautLambdaHandler`, but that fails because no bean is registered of that type.

Comment: `"Specifically, this doesn't work as expected..."` - What did you expect, and what happened?

Comment: I expect the mock to be used, but it wasn't used.

Answer (score 1):

Micronaut doesn't support testing lambdas with `@MicronautTest` for the time being. `MicronautLambdaHandler` and `MicronautRequestHandler` create their own context, completely separate from the one that is configured with `@MicronautTest` that actually registers your mocks. They are not beans either so injecting them does nothing.

This is a known issue (see [here](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/issues/330) for instance) and is being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@MicronautLambdaTest`](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aws/latest/api/io/micronaut/function/aws/test/annotation/MicronautLambdaTest.html) which will configure a suitable `ApplicationContext` for use in a Lambda environment.

Example from the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aws/latest/guide/#lambdaTesting):

```java
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;
import io.micronaut.function.aws.test.annotation.MicronautLambdaTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;

@MicronautLambdaTest
public class RequestHandlerTest {
    @Inject
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    void testHandler() {
        SampleRequestHandler sampleRequestHandler = new SampleRequestHandler(context);
        // ...
    }
}
```